# How can I count different types in a column in sql?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, pivot

```
Data:
        QID  Type DOB
        -------------
        1    1    01/01/1980
        1    2    03/01/1981
        1    2    01/02/1991
        1    1    01/01/1980
        1    2    03/01/1981
        1    3    01/02/1991
        1    1    01/01/1980
        2    2    03/01/1981
        2    2    01/02/1991
        2    1    01/01/1980
        2    2    03/01/1981
        2    2    01/02/1991
```

I need to select query that get this result:

```
    QID  Type(1) Type(2) Type(3)
    ----------------------------
     1     3        3       1
     2     1        4       0
```

I should use Function or can embedded in select query?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `PIVOT` operator, like this:

```
SELECT
   QID, ISNULL([1],0) AS [Type(1)], ISNULL([2],0) AS [Type(2)], ISNULL([3],0) AS [Type(3)]
FROM
   (SELECT QID, Type, COUNT(*) AS row_count
   FROM MyTable
   GROUP BY QID, Type) AS t
PIVOT
   (SUM([row_count]) FOR Type IN ([1],[2],[3])) AS PivotTable;
```

[BOL article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) about using `PIVOT` and `UNPIVOT`.

[SQL Fiddle with demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9b6a3/2/0)